# Can HTTP Post be used for streaming live video to a server?

Tags: http, video-streaming, http-post, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

Can a client use HTTP Post to stream live video to a server? If not, what protocol should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can, like in the case of the [RTMPT protocol](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/red5/rtmpt-protocol/) (Real Time Messaging Protocol tunneled over HTTP) which uses HTTP 1.1 POST to traverse firewalls.

Other `HTTP` streaming protocols include: `HLS`, `DASH`, `HDS` or `Smooth`.